# What exactly am I supossed to enter into the KerasRegressor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

I am running a simple MNIST data experiment and I want to find out how the `RandomizedSearchCV` and `KerasRegressor` functions work and optimize the parameters I am using. My code seems to almost be working but doesn't.

```
def build_model(n_hidden, n_neurons, learning_rate):  
  model = keras.models.Sequential()
  #add the input layer
  model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[28, 28]))
  for layer in range(n_hidden):
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(n_neurons, activation="relu"))
# output layer
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))
  optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate)
  model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
 optimizer="sgd",
 metrics=["accuracy"])
  return model

keras_reg = KerasRegressor(model=build_model)

param_distribs = {
 "n_hidden": [0, 1, 2, 3],
 "n_neurons": np.arange(1, 100),
  "learning_rate": reciprocal(3e-4, 3e-2)
}
rnd_search_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(keras_reg, param_distribs, n_iter=10, cv=3)
rnd_search_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

When I change `KerasRegressor(model=build_model)` to `KerasRegressor(model=build_model, learning_rate = 0.01, n_hidden = 5, n_neurons = 100)` it does work but I want to test for the parameters I initialized. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: ValueError: Invalid parameter learning_rate for estimator KerasRegressor.
This issue can likely be resolved by setting this parameter in the KerasRegressor constructor:
`KerasRegressor(learning_rate=0.00033094376013917707)`
Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`

Comment: What is `reciprocal`? Do you define it somewhere in the code?

Answer (score 0):

The key change is that you specify `build_fn=build_model` when creating `KerasRegressor`. This way, `KerasRegressor` knows to call the `build_model` function with the hyperparameters provided during the random search.

Now, you can run the randomized search with the specified hyperparameter distributions. The random search will explore different combinations of hyperparameters, and you'll be able to find the best set of hyperparameters for your model.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work unfortunately, I get this error: ValueError: Invalid parameter learning_rate for estimator KerasRegressor.
This issue can likely be resolved by setting this parameter in the KerasRegressor constructor:
`KerasRegressor(learning_rate=0.00033094376013917707)`
Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`

Answer (score 0):

Problems with your code:

1. In your `build_model()`, you have 3 parameters, which you would need
   to either initialize when calling the function or set a default
   value for each of them. Also you set `optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate)` but during model compilation
   you are setting `optimizer = 'sgd'` which by default would ignore
   your `learning_rate`.
2. It's a bit confusing that you are trying to use `KerasRegressor` to
   experiment on MNIST which is a classification task. You
   would need to replace `KerasRegressor` with `KerasClassifier`.

Here's a minimal example using [Fashion MNIST](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/fashion_mnist) dataset:

```
# required imports
import tensorflow
from keras.datasets import fashion_mnist
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier
import numpy as np  

# loading the fashion_mnist data and creating train/valid split
(X_train_full, y_train_full), (X_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
X_valid, X_train = X_train_full[:5000], X_train_full[5000:]
y_valid, y_train = y_train_full[:5000], y_train_full[5000:]

# model definition
input_shape=X_train[0].shape
def build_model(n_hidden, n_neurons, learning_rate, input_shape=input_shape):
    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=input_shape))
    for layer in range(n_hidden):
        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(n_neurons, activation="relu"))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))
    opt = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"])
    return model

# paramter distribution
param_distribs = {
"n_hidden": [0, 1, 2, 3],
"n_neurons": np.arange(1, 100).tolist(),
"learning_rate": np.arange(3e-4, 3e-2).tolist()
}

# initializing classifier
keras_clf = KerasClassifier(build_model, n_hidden=param_distribs["n_hidden"], n_neurons=param_distribs["n_neurons"], learning_rate=param_distribs["learning_rate"], verbose=1)

# model fitting and parameter search
rnd_search_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(keras_clf, param_distribs, n_iter=10, cv=5)
rnd_search_cv.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid))

# get best parameters 
rnd_search_cv.best_params_
```